# Values for nested fields not saving without error | Rails 5.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, nested-attributes

I'm working on a Rails 5.2 application requiring the storing of a `Quote`, and one `QuoteLineItem` to go wwith it (`Quote` `has_one :quote_line_item`, `QuoteLineItem` `belongs_to :quote`). I've set it all up according to documentation, however when submitting the `quotes#edit` for (which contains `fields_for @quote.quote_line_item...`), the values for the `Quote` record are updated in the database, however values for the `QuoteLineItem` are not. No error is thrown on submission, and no "Unpermitted params..." message in server logs.

**Quote Model**

```rb
class Quote < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :quote_line_item, inverse_of: :quote, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :quote_line_item, update_only: true
end
```

**QuoteLineItem Model**

```rb
class QuoteLineItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :quote, inverse_of: :quote_line_item, touch: true
end
```

**Quotes Controller**

```rb
class QuotesController < ApplicationController
  def update
    @quote = Quote.find(params[:id])

    if @quote.update(quote_params)
      flash[:success] = "Quote was successfully updated."
      redirect_to @quote
    else
      flash[:error] = "Quote was not updated. Please try again."
      render :edit
    end
  end

  private
    def quote_params
      params.require(:quote).permit(:issued_at, quote_line_item_attributes: [ :kind, :description, :price ])
    end
end
```

**Quotes Edit View**

```
<%= form_for @quote do |quote_form| %>
  <% if @quote.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@quote.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this quote from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
        <% @quote.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
          <li><%= message %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <%= quote_form.label :issued_at %>
  <%= quote_form.datetime_field :issued_at %>

  <%= fields_for :quote_line_item, @quote.quote_line_item do |quote_line_item_fields| %>
    <%= quote_line_item_fields.label :description %><br>
    <%= quote_line_item_fields.text_field :description %>

    <%= quote_line_item_fields.label :price %>
    <%= quote_line_item_fields.number_field :price, step: :any %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**Server Logs**

```
Started PATCH "/quotes/62" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-11-12 13:01:46 +0800
Processing by QuotesController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"bVa+vhRayuPDhe5xkLcK2rm10zQ9oHvtDSZsKDhMBsdX/JDjf6uXsnIJ7gM/yP7Lt9E+aBGIR9WCoLU2uNhgVQ==", "quote"=>{"issued_at"=>"12/11/2018 11:05 AM"}, "quote_line_item"=>{"description"=>"QuoteLineItem description goes here...", "price"=>"800.00"}, "commit"=>"Save", "id"=>"62"}
  Quote Load (3.8ms)  SELECT  `quotes`.* FROM `quotes` WHERE `quotes`.`id` = 62 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/controllers/quotes_controller.rb:127
   (0.7ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/quotes_controller.rb:53
   (3.6ms)  COMMIT
  ↳ app/controllers/quotes_controller.rb:53
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/quotes/62
Completed 302 Found in 44ms (ActiveRecord: 9.3ms)
```

Is there a reason this shouldn't be working?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please add log when you hit the update action?

Comment: @Vishal I've added server logs for the `quotes#update` action.

Comment: check your parameters for `quote_line_item` it should be `quote_line_items_attributes` . can you please try with this `  accepts_nested_attributes_for :quote_line_items, update_only: true
` and check how parameters are passing with this.

Comment: @Vishal thanks for the suggestion. With your suggested updates, I receive the error `No association found for name 'quote_line_items'. Has it been defined yet?`. The documentation shows that the model should be referenced in a singular form if the association is a `has_one`. Thanks

Comment: Okay, it should be only`accepts_nested_attributes_for :quote_line_item, update_only: true`, but you need to pass the parameters correctly. in form, try this `<%= fields_for :quote_line_item, @quote.quote_line_item do |quote_line_item_fields| %>`

Comment: Let me know if it isn't working

Comment: @Vishal Thanks for your suggestion. Declaring `fields_for` as you suggested in above comment didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: can you please update log, after adding new syntax of fields_for

Comment: I notice that the form parameters being parsed to `quotes#update` look like this: `"quote"=>{"issued_at"=>"12/11/2018 11:05 AM"}, "quote_line_item"=>{"description"=>"Line item description goes here...", "price"=>"200.00"}`, notice the `quote_line_item` hash outside of the `quote` hash. Is this expected behaviour, or should the `quote_line_item` has be nested within the `quote` hash?

Comment: and what if you only use `<%= fields_for :quote_line_item do |quote_line_item_fields| %>`

Comment: @Vishal I've updated the question with your suggested `fields_for` syntax and the resulting server log. Regarding your most recent `fields_for` syntax suggestion, this makes no difference other than the form stops pre-filling the fields with their existing values. Thanks

Comment: last try, please add `@quote.build_quote_line_item` in your new action

Comment: @Vishal Thanks for your suggestion. Adding `@quote.build_quote_line_item` as suggested seems to destroy any existing `QuoteLineItem` record for the `Quote` in preparation for the replacement record that's being "built". Thanks for your input.

Comment: The only thing you missing is name of parameters for nested parameters.

Comment: most probably what you are missing is :id in the permit params for quote_line_item_attributes. Therefore permit params would be something like this:  params.require(:quote).permit(:issued_at, quote_line_item_attributes: [ :id, :kind, :description, :price ])

Comment: @AkshayGoyal Thanks for your suggestion. I've tried adding the `:id` parameter to the `quote_line_item_attributes` permitted params as you suggested, but it didn't seem to make any difference. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try referencing `quote_form` before your `fields_for`:

```
<%= form_for @quote do |quote_form| %>

  ...

  <%= quote_form.fields_for :quote_line_item do |quote_line_item_fields| %>
  #   ^ <- Add here

    ...

  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

After updating this, check that the parameters being passed to `quotes#edit` are nested:

i.e: `"quote"=>{"issued_at"=>"12/11/2018 11:05 AM", "quote_line_item"=>{"description"=>"Line item description goes here...", "price"=>"200.00"}, "id"=>"63"}`